# Can anyone id this adult tricycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, tricycle

Can anyone id this tricycle?  It has been painted over.  It used to be a sky blue color. The tires are 24"x 1 3/8ths".  My friend who gave it to me said it's at least 20 years old, but I think it's actually much older than that.  I'm planning on restoring it so any info would be awesome. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've edited the question to include your images in your post.  That way if the files vanish, then the question still makes sense in the future.

Comment: Also, those pebbles made it difficult to keep the photo's resolution while staying under the 2.0 Mbyte limit imposed by SE.  Hence the somewhat brutal cropping.

Comment: That saddle is absolutely enormous - do you think its original? Could be a handy hook to identify the bike.

Comment: Thank you for the editing.  I think the saddle is original.

Comment: The triple-plate fork crown is also a pretty old style. The tops of the fork legs should be sealed btw, it looks like rain can get in at the moment.

Comment: I would guess earlier than 1970.  But if the rims are aluminum vs steel (hard to guess, with that image) then I might make it 1975.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the trike is a 1975 Free Spirit.

Comment: Awesome finding - well done!  Thank you for coming back and closing the loop.